# Can anyone tell me how to do multiple rank update of a non square matrix?

Tags: matrices

I had seen the rank one update for pseudo inverse in book "Generalized inverses of linear transformation" by S.L. Campbell. But i want to do rank 3 or rank 4 update in my existing matrix. Please tell me is it possible to do so? And where can i find such methods?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Updating_the_pseudoinverse has  couple of references.

Comment: Those formulas are primarily valid for square matrix update as i had already checked with my case long before. My matrix element has values very close so all of them are failing when i am doing inv(AA'). To get rid of this i tried above reference of Campbell which is very much satisfactory with my case. If u can tell me another ref like one above i will be grateful to you.

Answer (score 0):

This paper may be useful for you.

http://www.math.nyu.edu/~riedel/ranksiam.pdf